# Бот не реагирует на команду, в консоли ничего нету

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Бот не реагирует именно на команду -country (префикс бота "-")
Остальные команды работают без ошибок.
В интерпретаторе пустота, нету никаких сообщений об ошибках.

Код:

```
import random
import discord

@bot.command()
async def country(ctx, arg):
    country = ["россия", "китай", "германия", "франция", "канада", "украина", "беларусь", "япония", "австралия"]
    россия = ''
    китай = ''
    германия = ''
    франция = ''
    канада = ''
    украина = ''
    беларусь = ''
    япония = ''
    австралия = ''
    answ = random.choice(country)
    cuest = f'{answ}'
    await ctx.send(f'Какой страны этот флаг? \n{country}')
    if arg == answ:
        await ctx.send('Вы угадали!')
    elif arg != answ:
        await ctx.send(f'Вы проиграли... Это была {answ}')
```

---

Comment: Ех так вам надо в самом дискорде писать а не в консоле, и разве переменные могут быть не только латиниуей?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570301/how-can-i-make-my-discord-bot-respond-to-the-correct-answer

Comment: насчёт латиницы я попробую, но я думаю дело не в этом, команду я писал я в самом дискорде, а в консоли ошибок не было